# reading from buffer/s - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, buffer

I am using `glGenBuffers`,which creates a handle/s that is used to refer to the buffer when talking to gl.Can I use the handle to read the content of the buffer/s?
If yes - how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to read data from a [Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). There is [`glGetBufferSubData`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetBufferSubData), which directly copies buffer data into a pointer of your choice.

You can also [map the buffer for reading](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping). That requires using [`glMapBufferRange`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMapBufferRange) (or [`glMapBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMapBuffer) if you're old-school), which you can use to get a pointer to the buffer objects data and read directly.

Comment: but which is better tho

Comment: @AidanConnelly: None of them are "better" There are some that are more appropriate for your specific usage pattern, but that's it.